# What information should be included in a Tag Wiki Excerpt for a film/tv series title tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

When creating tag wiki excerpts for film or TV show titles, what information should be included? Right now, every excerpt seems to be different, which makes some of them more helpful than others.

Which of the following should be expected in Title tags:

- year (for TV series, often the debut year or a year range if the show has ended)
- genre
- format (film/documentary/TV sitcom/mini-series/etc.)
- director (film)
- main actor/s
- network (TV)
- plot description
- other(?)

I think that standardizing this could make the title tags a bit more obvious and having specific guidance may help users create or edit these more easily.

### Please note, this relates to the excerpt - the box that appears when you hover over a tag or what you see when you view the [tags page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags).

These are short, space-limited areas. I am not talking about the full wiki entry that allows formatting and linking and images.

Answer (score 6):

The tag wiki excerpt is formally called *User Guidance* and that is what is should be. In the case of a film or a series, it should give enough information for a user to be able to discern tags for different works with similar titles.

It should at least have

- the full name of the work
- year of release
- the name of

  - the producer in the case of TV series
  - the name of the director for films
- the name of the primary stars, both of the actors and of the characters they portray
- the most important accolades (Oscars / Emmys for work, producer/director, actors)

An example using *The Blacklist*:

> The Blacklist (2013) is a crime TV series produced by John Brokenkamp, featuring Megan Boone as Elizabeth Keen, an FBI-profiler, and James Spader as Raymond Reddington, a criminal on the FBI's most-wanted list, working together to bring down other high profile criminals.

An example using *Jurassic Park*:

> Jurassic Park (1993) is an Academy Award-winning science fiction film directed by Steven Spielberg and the first instalment of a franchise of the same name. It featured ground-breaking CGI to depict live dinosaurs.

Answer (score 1):

A tag wiki excerpt should answer two types of questions:

- Assuming I do not know anything about this movie, what should I know about it that would allow me to now say that I am familiar with it? Or simply, what was it all about?
- Since I follow certain real-life events and personalities, who are associated with this movie, and did it receive any accolades?

A tag wiki excerpt should have the following:

- Fully articulated name, including a former name or common alternate name
- Year, country of production, and genres
- Director(s), writer(s), stars, any accolades
- A very short, non-spoiler plot description

Side note for the rest of the wiki:

- For those who are now eager to garner more information, convenient links to additional resources would be nice.
- Many productions are part of a series (or part of a universe), so that association should be stated – along with how it fits into that series/universe.  A long running TV series, should also add how many seasons the show was/is active.

Comment: We're talking about the excerpts, not the wiki. As I commented on the other answer, links are not appropriate in wiki excerpts.

Comment: You can't use code in an excerpt, so the link would be a bare link and not clickable... this is less than useful.

Answer (score -1):

A Tag Wiki excerpt (the part you see when you hover over a tag) should be somewhat brief, but informative, imho.

My list of what should be on a tag-wiki excerpt should be, from most to least important, is:

- Year of Initial Release (for TV, whether on-going or year of last season)
- Genre
- Main actors and actresses
- Country of Origin
- Director/s and Producer/s
- TV Info (networks, format, etc)

I'm not a fan of putting the whole plot description.  A short description of the premise should be enough.

Comment: Links should not be included in wiki excerpts

Comment: @Catija are we talking about the usage guidance section (what you seen when you hover over a tag) or the actual tag wiki (the info you have to click to get to)?

Comment: @Catija if we're talking about the tag wiki, then I 100% disagree.  Go look at the top tags for SO, they have really good usage of links to external sites that are important to the tag.

Comment: Tag wiki excerpts are the blurb that appears when you hover over the tag name.

Comment: @Catija ahh, i'll adjust my answer then.