# Top tags requiring a tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Tag wikis are descriptions of tags that are displayed when you hover over a tag or [when you are tagging a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74645/162827). Tags should at least have tag wiki excerpts (usage guidance) to help users understand what a question tagged with that particular tag is about, and help them choose the right tags for their questions.

If you consider yourself knowledgeable about a movie or TV show, please consider contributing tag wikis and excerpts. Stick close to our [format for tag wiki excerpts](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2579/1006), and note that those with [less than 20K rep](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) will need their edits to be approved before going live.

[5K rep reviewers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), please make sure you reject [suggestions that are plagiarized or copied without attribution from other sites.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Top tags without a tag wiki or tag wiki excerpt

Do you want to contribute to the community? Do you want to earn some reputation points? You can do both by proposing tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts. You will get **+2 reputation** (if you have less than [20K rep](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)) for each approved tag wiki or tag wiki excerpt you create. That's **+4 reputation** for both the tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt. *Sounds good, right?*

##### For each tag wiki you create (and that is *approved*), please remove it from the list below.

The source for the following list is this [SEDE query: "Top tags without excerpts"](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/668431/top-tags-without-excerpts). (Note that the query can be up to a week out of date.) The tags are sorted by question count in descending order.

Please follow the **[guidelines in this meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2579/1006)** for writing tag wiki excerpts, and remember, [*do not plagiarize content*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)!

(This list only includes tags with 8 or more questions. To see a list of all tags with no tag wiki excerpts, use the [aforementioned SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/668431/top-tags-without-excerpts).)

| Tag | Question Count |
| --- | --- |
| [mank](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mank) | 21 |
| [1917](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1917) | 20 |
| [tinker-tailor-soldier-spy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tinker-tailor-soldier-spy) | 19 |
| [monsterverse](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monsterverse) | 18 |
| [the-irishman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-irishman) | 18 |
| [the-good-place](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-good-place) | 15 |
| [the-handmaids-tale](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-handmaids-tale) | 15 |
| [mollys-game](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mollys-game) | 14 |
| [screenwriter](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenwriter) | 13 |
| [set-design](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-design) | 13 |
| [peaky-blinders](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peaky-blinders) | 12 |
| [the-lion-king](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lion-king) | 12 |
| [top-gun-maverick](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/top-gun-maverick) | 12 |
| [brooklyn-nine-nine](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brooklyn-nine-nine) | 11 |
| [top-gun](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/top-gun) | 11 |
| [baahubali-2-the-conclusion](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baahubali-2-the-conclusion) | 10 |
| [billions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/billions) | 10 |
| [lost-in-space-2018](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-in-space-2018) | 10 |
| [projection](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projection) | 10 |
| [the-girl-with-the-dragon-tattoo](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-girl-with-the-dragon-tattoo) | 10 |
| [the-queens-gambit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-queens-gambit) | 10 |
| [tom-and-jerry](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tom-and-jerry) | 10 |
| [us](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us) | 10 |
| [bohemian-rhapsody](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bohemian-rhapsody) | 9 |
| [cheers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheers) | 9 |
| [doctor-sleep](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-sleep) | 9 |
| [midway-2019](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midway-2019) | 9 |
| [ralph-breaks-the-internet](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ralph-breaks-the-internet) | 9 |
| [red-sparrow](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-sparrow) | 9 |
| [a-bridge-too-far](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-bridge-too-far) | 8 |
| [alita-battle-angel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alita-battle-angel) | 8 |
| [die-hard-with-a-vengeance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/die-hard-with-a-vengeance) | 8 |
| [glass-onion-a-knives-out-mystery](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glass-onion-a-knives-out-mystery) | 8 |
| [greyhound](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greyhound) | 8 |
| [hereditary](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hereditary) | 8 |
| [hidden-figures](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidden-figures) | 8 |
| [limitless-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limitless-tv) | 8 |
| [red-dragon](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-dragon) | 8 |
| [sacred-games](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sacred-games) | 8 |
| [sin-city](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-city) | 8 |
| [spartacus-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spartacus-tv) | 8 |
| [spider-man-no-way-home](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider-man-no-way-home) | 8 |
| [terminator-dark-fate](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator-dark-fate) | 8 |
| [the-big-short](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-big-short) | 8 |
| [the-girl-who-leapt-through-time](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-girl-who-leapt-through-time) | 8 |

If none of these tags interest you, you can check out the "**[Tag Wikis you might be able to provide](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/581815/tag-wikis-i-might-be-able-to-provide)**" SEDE query to see a list of tags that you have asked or answered questions about that do not yet have a tag wiki.

Comment: 'Screenwriter' just needs to die. A quick glance reveals that it's not consistently used