# Rejected tag wiki suggestion

Tags: discussion, moderation, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

This month, I’ve posted a couple of questions under a new tag ([five-nights-at-freddys](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/five-nights-at-freddys)).  Being a new tag, it didn’t have an existing tag wiki, so (after consulting [this meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2579/what-information-should-be-included-in-a-tag-wiki-excerpt-for-a-film-tv-series-t)) I wrote up a tag wiki for it myself (see below).

But, I’ve just had the tag wiki edit suggestion [**Rejected**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/96248) by a moderator, as:

> This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community *specifically*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author. See: [How to reference material written by others](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Being accused of plagiarism is offensive.  I spent quite a while writing this tag wiki.  Sure, I had to look at a number of sources to double check factual information, but I certainly didn’t copy anything; I wrote every sentence in my own words, and didn’t even paraphrase — else I would have added citations.

**Which parts of my suggested tag wiki are supposedly copied?** and **What sources am I supposed to have copied from?**

**Is there something else wrong with my proposed tag wiki?**

---

### My tag wiki suggestion to [five-nights-at-freddys](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/five-nights-at-freddys)

> *Five Nights at Freddy’s* (2023) was directed by Emma Tammi and produced by Blumhouse Productions and Cawthon Productions from a screenplay by Scott Cawthon, Emma Tammi, and Seth Cuddeback.
>
> This film is a supernatural mystery thriller about haunted animatronic mascots at an abandoned pizzeria. The story is loosely based on Scott Cawthon’s *Five Nights at Freddy’s* video game and book franchise.
>
> The franchise began in 2014 with Cawthon’s original *Five Nights at Freddy’s* video game.  This indie thriller survival game features jump scares from the animatronic mascots.  The success of this game led to nearly a dozen mainline games and several series of books that continue to develop the story slowly and in different directions.
>
> While there is much in common between the video games, the books, and the movie, the characters and stories are significantly different.
>
> #### Stars
>
> - Josh Hutcherson (as Mike Schmidt)
> - Piper Rubio (as Abby Schmidt)
> - Elizabeth Lail (as Vanessa Shelly)
> - Matthew Lillard (as Steve Raglan / William Afton)
> - Mary Stuart Masterson (as Aunt Jane)
> - Several haunted animatronic puppets (Freddy, Bonnie, Chica & Mr Cupcake, Foxy, Golden Freddy) designed by [Jim Henson’s Creature Shop](https://creatureshop.com/).
>
> #### Reception
>
> *Five Nights at Freddy’s* was released over the Halloween weekend of 2023 and went on to make nearly $300m gross (a record for Blumhouse Productions).  While the film received poor reviews from the critics, it was a success with the fans of the franchise (many of whom had been following the popular video game series for nearly a decade).  FNaF was nominated for the People’s Choice Awards in *The Drama Movie of the Year* category.

Comment: I'm not commenting on the plagarism element of the question but it *reads* like a Wikipedia entry. I applaud your contribution but it seems to me to be waaay too long and detailed. Most tag wikis are a couple of short paragraphs at best. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one

Comment: @Paulie_D Do you have an example of a well written tag wiki for a film on M&TV?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be plagiarized (ran it through Quetext plagiarism checker). @Paulie_D That's not a valid reason to reject a tag wiki suggestion.

Comment: The length seems fine to me. I think it could do without the "Reception" section, but it's not a big deal. There's no rule/policy that says tag wikis must be of a certain length.

Comment: I put the reception section because it’s interesting; it made a surprising amount much money and was a success with the fans, but the critics didn’t like it at all.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't reject it but my finger hovered over the button. I assumed it was plagiarised. I checked some of the phrases and they seemed like the sort of thing you'd read on Wikipedia but maybe reworded using some kind of AI tool

Comment: Indeed, in my *opinion* the tag wiki could have consisted of just the first two paragraphs. The rest is either irrelevant to the movie (as it's about the game) or just trivia not really appropriate (again IMO) to a tag wiki.

Comment: Thank you for being thorough! I also believe rejecting an edit on the basis of plagiarism requires more than just a hunch. And any descent tag wiki is already better than no tag wiki.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'd like to thank you for taking time to write the tag wiki.

As already pointed out in comments, it appeared as copied content to me as well. Plus, it had too many details.

I'd suggest following:

- Please remove the reception. There could be many examples where a movie made a lot of money despite receiving negative reviews.
- Star cast can go in one line with primary cast members.
- Start with name and release year followed by short story description.
- Name of crew members can go in the second paragraph and 2-3 sentences should be enough.

Comment: Do you use any method to test for plagiarism, or does "appear to be" mean "assume that"?

Answer (score 4):

I’ve re-drafted the tag wiki (below).  I took out some stuff as suggested, and reorganised it a bit.  I still haven’t got a synopsis of the story because (as I found when drafting the original suggestion) it’s very hard to write one without getting caught up on irrelevant details.

---

This is a community wiki so that other users can edit it further before I resubmit it as a suggestion.

#### Tag Wiki (2nd Draft)

> *Five Nights at Freddy’s* (2023) is a supernatural mystery thriller featuring haunted animatronic mascots in an abandoned pizzeria. The film is based on a video game and book franchise created by Scott Cawthon.
>
> The movie was directed by Emma Tammi and produced by Blumhouse Productions.  It stars Josh Hutcherson (as Mike), Piper Rubio (as Abby), Elizabeth Lail (as Vanessa), Matthew Lillard (as Steve Raglan / William Afton), and Mary Stuart Masterson (as Aunt Jane).  Jim Henson’s Creature Shop designed the haunted animatronics.
>
> The franchise began with Cawthon’s video game release in 2014 by the same name.  This indie thriller survival game features jump scares from the animatronic mascots.  The success of this game led to nearly a dozen mainline games and several series of books that continue to develop the story slowly and in different directions.  While there is much in common between the video games, the books, and the movie, the characters and stories are significantly different.

Comment: It’s been over a weeks without any comments or edits to this 2nd draft, so I’ve suggest the above as the tag wiki…

Comment: I've approved [your tag wiki edit suggestion](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/96265).